# На сайте перестал работать Flash

Tags: веб-программирование, flash

Перестал работать флэш на сайте, в связи последних веяний в Адоб.
Можно ли его как-то самому запустить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "Перестал работать флэш на сайте" означает, что вы хозяин сайта или браузера, в котором этот сайт открывается?

Comment: Типа хозяин. Ковыряю сейчас swf2js.com/en/
Но все равно показывает картинку-перенаправления на сайт адоб.

Comment: RIP https://xakep.ru/2020/12/10/flash-eol/